# Request to the simple node js web server

Tags: node.js

Consider this code:

```
var http = require("http");
http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    console.log("Request received");
    response.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/plain" });
    response.write("Hello World");
    response.end();
}).listen(8888, "127.0.0.1");
```

When run this code and go to the `http://127.0.0.1:8888/`in the node's console i get 3 `Request received` i know one of them for the favicon and other is main request but why i get the 3 `Request received`?

Comment: It looks like you use a browser. So you should be able to see the detail of the requests it makes in the developer tools.

Comment: when i do `curl 127.0.0.1:8888` i get only one. With Chrome it's 2

Comment: I also get 2 with Chrome. Makes perfect sense then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on your client (browser).

There are plugins/extensions in browsers that might create extra requests, Chrome will try to load favicon all the time, while Firefox for example will try once and in case with failure - will not retry.

Add this into your callback to see what is exactly is requested:

```
console.log(request.url, request.method)
```